# How to update a part of a json value

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-json

I have the following data and MySQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl(
  id INT,
  dataset_query longtext
);
INSERT INTO my_tbl(id, dataset_query) VALUES (1, '{"database":1,"native":{"query":"SELECT * FROM view_1.device","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"}');
INSERT INTO my_tbl(id, dataset_query) VALUES (2, '{"database":1,"native":{"query":"SELECT id, name FROM view_1.request","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"}');
INSERT INTO my_tbl(id, dataset_query) VALUES (3, '{"database":3,"native":{"query":"SELECT id, name, age FROM view_3.person","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"}');
```

I need to change the following data in the dataset_query column:

- From `"database":1` to `"database":2`
- Replace `view_1` with `view_2`

To update the database ID, I use the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE
    my_tbl
SET
    dataset_query = JSON_SET(dataset_query, "$.database", 2) 
WHERE 
    json_extract(dataset_query, '$.database') = 1;
```

How can I update the `dataset_query` column in the `my_tbl` table to replace all occurrences of `view_1` with `view_2`?

The expected result is as follows:

| id | dataset_query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"database":2,"native":{"query":"SELECT * FROM view_2.device","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"} |
| 2 | {"database":2,"native":{"query":"SELECT id, name FROM view_2.request","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"} |
| 3 | {"database":3,"native":{"query":"SELECT id, name, age FROM view_3.person","template-tags":{}},"type":"native"} |

Db fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nw7sEBcF2i8eioWQawqdmD/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE()` function. Use the path `$.native.query` to get the nested object property.

```
UPDATE my_tbl
SET dataset_query = JSON_REPLACE(
        dataset_query, 
        '$.native.query',
        REPLACE(dataset_query->>'$.native.query', 'view_1', 'view_2'))
WHERE dataset_query->>'$.native.query' LIKE '%view_1%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update my_tbl
set dataset_query = JSON_SET(
  dataset_query, '$.native.query',
  REPLACE(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(dataset_query, '$.native.query')),
    'view_1', 'view_2'
  )
);
```

Db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3jyZcYR33X9wHZPQ6sahf/1

Comment: I've updated my dbfiddle. I forgot to save it the first time.